# Why does nobody but Daenerys call themselves King (or Queen) of the Rhoynar?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the [A Song of Ice and Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire) series, everyone who claims to be the rightful heir to the Iron throne uses the following title:

> [King or Queen] of the Andals, the [Rhoynar](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhoynar) and the [First Men](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/First_Men), Lord of the Seven Kingdoms and Protector of the Realm

However, in [Game of Thrones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones) the Rhoynar are always omitted And up until now I had assumed this was because they were never mentioned in other contexts and it was just to avoid confusing people. For example in S04E05- [**First of His Name**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_of_His_Name) when Tommen is crowned king, the [High Septon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/High_Septon_%28title%29) crowns him:

> Tommen of the house Baratheon, First of his name, King of the Andals and the first Men, Lord of the Seven Kingdoms and Protector of the Realm

However in the most recent episode, [**The Children**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_%28Game_of_Thrones%29), Daenerys (for what I believe to be the first time), is announced as also holding this honour:

[image: Daenerys' titles in S04E10- The Children]

Have I missed previous mentions or was this just an error added in by a fan working in the graphics department?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Rhoynar are the men who used to traditionally live along the banks of the river Rhoyne. However, 700 years before the Aegon's Conquest around 250,000 of the Rhoynar died in the expansion of the Valyrian freehold. In such circumstances, a warrior-queen named Nymeria fled with the remaining Rhoynar to the Dorne in southern Westeros. Nymeria then married a Dornish prince Mors Martell, and helped him secure his seat at Sunspear. The Rhoynar have lived among the Dornish since then, and all of the Dornish men today have some Rhoynar blood in them. Hence they are still referred to as Rhoynar men.

By S04E05, the Kingdom of Dorne had not been properly introduced to the viewers; it was only after Oberyn Martell's duel with the Mountain that Dorne came into focus. I think that's why they did not include "King of Rhoynar" in Tommen's title, but did that in the last episode for Daenerys' title.

Comment: Interesting theory. But wasn't *Oberyn* introduced much earlier, even before the Purple Wedding (i.e. before *Tommen*'s coronation)?

Answer (score 3):

Because the Rhoynar are the Dornish, and when the Targaryen dynasty fell, the Dornish immediately declared independency, and the Baratheons did not have the power nor will to put them back under their subjugation. Therefore, the Dornish and thus the Rhoynar have not been a part of the seven kingdoms since Aerys Targaryen. Because of this, the kings after him cannot claim to be kings of "the Andals, Rhoynar, and the First Men", because they are, in fact, only kings of the Andals and the first men. Daenerys however, intends to conquer all of Westeros, including Dorne. Therefore, she calls herself queen of the Andals, Rhoynar, and the First Men, something the others cannot do, because Dorne is independent and thus they are not kings of the Rhoynar.

Comment: -1 This is not accurate.  Dorne is still a part of the seven kingdoms at this point, although they've always been a bit more independent then the rest.

Comment: Dorne is a principality, hence Doran was Prince Martell.  Not quite independent but still part of the severn kingdoms. Other regions have Wardens and Lord Protectors

Answer (score 0):

This may be long shot and speculative answer.

> **The Rhoynar are one of the three major ethnic groups from which the
>   humans of Westeros descend,** the others being the Andals and the First
>   Men. **They were a culture of river-faring people who dwelt on the banks
>   of the immense river Rhoyne in Essos. After being forced to flee in
>   ten thousand ships during the Rhoynish Wars with Valyria, the
>   surviving Rhoynar eventually settled in Dorne in southern Westeros.**
>
> **While most Rhoynar integrated into Dornish society, especially into
>   the so-called "salty Dornishmen", the orphans of the Greenblood have
>   retained their Rhoynish heritage and language**. The Lord of the
>   Seven Kingdoms, who sits Iron Throne, claims the title of King of the
>   Andals, the Rhoynar, and the First Men.

As other answers have explained, the Rhoynar integrated into Dornish society after wars with Valerya, were families like the Targaryens come from.

The reason that information *could matter more to book readers, is because *A Dance of Dragons* presents Danearys with several prospective husbands/suitors including Hizdahr zo Loraq (whom she marries, but is later imprisoned believed to be a traitor. On the TV series, he's murdered and does not appear as vindictive), [Euron Grejoy](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Euron_Greyjoy) (who sends his brother Victarion to seek out Dany, but it's possibly a ruse given a few factors), [Young Griff](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Rhaegar)) (a young man claiming to be a surviving Targaryen, Aegon), and the [Prince Frog](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Quentyn_Martell), whose really Quentyn Martell...

> Daario brings the feigned turncloaks to Queen Daenerys in her audience
>   chamber and presents them as recruits of his Stormcrows. Quentyn and
>   his friends reveal that they are knights, but ask for privacy in order
>   to reveal their names. **After the court is cleared, Quentyn hands over
>   his "gift", a parchment containing a secret pact, signed by Ser Willem
>   Darry and Prince Oberyn Martell, with the Sealord of Braavos
>   witnessing the signatures. The pact was for Viserys Targaryen to wed
>   Quenty's sister, Arianne, in return for Dorne's support in helping the
>   exile regain the Iron Throne. With Viserys having died at Vaes
>   Dothrak, however, Quentyn now offers himself as a husband for Daenerys
>   in return for the support of Dorne.**

So it may be possible that one reason the *Game of Thrones* EPs/writers chose to add "Rhoyner" to Dany's dialogue may not just be because Dorne itself wasn't introduced until around this time, **but it could of been used as referencing and/or foreshadowing the book & tv events**...

> Some months later, when Olenna Tyrell accepts an invitation from
>   Ellaria Sand to Sunspear to discuss the possibilities of an alliance
>   against Cersei in the wake of the Sept of Baelor's destruction and the
>   resultant deaths of Margaery, Loras and Mace Tyrell, [Varys](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Varys) **reveals
>   himself as the true architect of the alliance, which is in fact to
>   provide a domestic beachhead for Daenerys's return. When Daenerys
>   finally sets sail for Westeros she has the combined might of Dorne,**
>   the Reach and most of the Iron Fleet, along with her Unsullied,
>   Dothraki, and dragons. Varys stands aboard Daenerys's flagship with
>   her, Tyrion and Missandei, having finally met his new Queen and
>   pledged his loyalty. With dragons flying in the skies, the second
>   Targaryen invasion of Westeros is now ready to begin.

Even though they inevitably decided not follow through on in it's entirely, Dany does come to join forces with Dorne, but through Varys instead of the *prospect of Quentyn Martell!